# Search for divs that contain specified text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a search function on my website, where I search for divs (and leave out the divs which didn't meet what I searched for. The div list looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class='subjects'>
    <div id='subject'>soccer</div>
    <div id='subject'>dancing</div>
    <div id='subject'>soap</div>
</div>
</body>
```

For instance, when I search for the 's' it doesn't show the div which the dancing inside and when you write 'soa' it shows soap only (not removing divs not matching, just don't show them).

I really have no experience with searching stuff, so all information is welcome.

ps. the tags I added are the languages that are available, if I need an extension: that's no problem.

Comment: id='subject' 3 place change them to class :)

Comment: You can't have multiple instances of an id.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` to do it, something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class='subjects'>
    <div>soccer</div>
    <div>dancing</div>
    <div>soap</div>
</div>

<input type="text" id='search' />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#search').on('input', function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('.subjects div').show();    
    $('.subjects div:not(:contains(' + text + '))').hide();
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrFhD/1/)**

Comment: Also check this funny aproach http://redotheweb.com/2013/05/15/client-side-full-text-search-in-css.html

Comment: He still uses js in this link so the title: "Client-side full-text search in CSS" might be abit wrong..

Comment: Yea. It's just one more funny approach. :)

Answer (score 2):

In POJS and only caring about modern browsers (supporting ECMA5 & HTML5, IE10+)

CSS

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="search"></input>
<div class="subjects">
    <div class="subject">soccer</div>
    <div class="subject">dancing</div>
    <div class="subject">soap</div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".subjects .subject"), function (subject) {
        if (subject.textContent.indexOf(evt.target.value) === -1) {
            subject.classList.add("hide");
        } else {
            subject.classList.remove("hide");
        }
    });
}, false);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ShQJ6/)

In POJS and cross-browser required (IE5.5+)

javascript

```
function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkTheDOM(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}

function classNameToArray(className) {
    return className.split(/ +/);
}

function getElementsByClassName(node, className) {
    var array = [],
        elements = node.getElementsByTagName("*"),
        elementsLength = elements.length,
        i = 0,
        element,
        classNames,
        classNamesLength,
        x;

    while (i < elementsLength) {
        element = elements[i];
        classNames = classNameToArray(element.className);
        for (x = 0, classNamesLength = classNames.length; x < classNamesLength; x += 1) {
            if (classNames[x] === className) {
                array.push(element);
                break;
            }
        }

        i += 1;
    }

    return array;
}

document.getElementById("search").onkeyup = function (evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event,
        target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        subjects = getElementsByClassName(document, "subjects"),
        subject = [],
        classnames,
        classNamesLength,
        classIndex,
        element,
        length,
        index,
        text;

    for (index = 0, length = subjects.length; index < length; index += 1) {
        subject = subject.concat(getElementsByClassName(subjects[index], "subject"));
    }

    for (index = 0, length = subject.length; index < length; index += 1) {
        text = "";
        element = subject[index];
        walkTheDOM(element, function (currentNode) {
            if (currentNode.nodeType === 3) {
                text += currentNode.nodeValue;
            }
        });

        classNames = classNameToArray(element.className);
        for (classIndex = classNames.length - 1; classIndex >= 0; classIndex -= 1) {
            if (classNames[classIndex] === "hide") {
                classNames.splice(classIndex, 1);
            }
        }

        if (text.indexOf(target.value) === -1) {
            classNames.push("hide");
        }

        element.className = classNames.join(" ");
    }
};
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/bt9Vm/)

Or in jQuery (IE6+ or IE9+ depends on jQuery version)

javascript

```
$("#search").keyup(function (evt) {
    var subject = $(".subjects .subject");

    subject.removeClass("hide");
    subject.each(function (index, element) {
        var $element = $(element);

        if ($element.text().indexOf(evt.target.value) === -1) {
            $element.addClass("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/gaT8Z/)

All of these examples use CSS to style the divs, so it is very easy to change your styling, if you don't want to just show/hide but maybe highlight or place a border.

Comment: You should remove the `display: none;` as typing something and removing it after will show all of them (and I want to show all of them, in general).

Comment: These are just examples which you can modify to suit your project,  your specifics were not clear to me from your question.