# Hiding the parent element when there is no matching descendant elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, html

Before I start, this is a kind of 'part 2' of [Search for divs that contain specified text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078526/search-for-divs-that-contain-specified-text)

Hey.
I got a list of divs, and each has several divs (to style), it looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class='divlist'>

<div>
    <div>abc</div><div>def</div><div>ghi</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

In the `body` tags I've also got a search (`<input type='text' id='search' />`)

and my jquery:

```
$('#search').on('input', function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('.divlist div').show();    
    $('.divlist div:not(:contains(' + text + '))').hide();
});
```

Now, if I search for `abc` it will remove the div containing `def` and `ghi`, although the search matched the div (the one with the abcdefghi inside).
So:
How would I make a search function that removes the main div if nothing matches (for instance, `j`) and show all of the divs inside the div containing the other divs no matter how many divs match.

Thanks in advance.

ps. if someone knows a better title, feel free to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filtering all the `div` elements, filter the `.divlist` elements:

```
$('.divlist:not(:contains(' + text + '))').hide();
```

Or their immediate `div` children using child selector:

```
$('.divlist > div:not(:contains(' + text + '))').hide();
```

You can also use `.filter()` method which is more efficient than expensive `:not(:contains())` selector:

```
$('.divlist > div').hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(text) > -1;   
}).show();
```

Comment: How would I exclude the div containing `abc` if it for example has `class="first3"`?